# Xbox One background music / task for UWP web view

Tags: uwp, background-task, xbox, background-music, xbox-one

I'd love to know if it's somehow possible to use background task / music for the Xbox One with web views from UWP.

For example to easily provide apps for web radios and streaming services like https://music.amazon.com/

From my understanding it seems not possible to achieve since you basically have to use the MediaPlayer API, but I also read something about unlimiting the memory constraints for background tasks (you cannot publish to store then) and maybe there's a way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd love to know if it's somehow possible to use background task / music for the Xbox One with web views from UWP.

Currently, UWP does not provide background music for [`WebView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview). Even though the engine of WebView control is Edge, there are many differences between them. Such as microsoft edge could background music via Microsoft Edge host service, but WebView control has not. If you do want this feature, please post this on [**UserVoice**](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform?query=pin%20secondary%20tile%20without%20user%20consent).

> but I also read something about unlimiting the memory constraints for background tasks (you cannot publish to store then)

As far as I know, there is no such task could be used, and we also do not recommend using non-secure apis.